# How to compare filenames with number in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have number of multiple files in a folder and their filenames contains alphanumeric values. For e.g. 045_abcd.sql, 34qqqq.sql, 87asdf.sql etc. I want to compare numbers in these filenames with another number stored in variable lets say `$× =37` and find out files which has number contain in filename greater than of that variable value. So here in this example result should be `045_abcd.sql` and `87asdf.sql`, basically it should compare 37 with all the files names and store result in another variable. And after that execute those files using invoke sql cmd. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here is what I have done so far considering above example:

```
$× =37

$y = Get-ChildItem -Path $PATH | Where-Object { ((! $_.PSIsContainer))} | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '\D+' }

$z = Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object {$_.Name -gt $x}
```

So the second command will rename all the files by removing all non digit characters including extension(.sql) so the output is:

```
34
45
87
```

and then third command gives me greater than value of $x = 37 i.e.

```
45
87
```

what I need is the entire filename after the comparison with $x so I that I can execute the .sql files using Invoke sql cmd

Comment: We are a community to help programmers and programming enthusiasts. That being said, it is expect that you show what you have done or tried before posting. This gives us something to build on. As of now this reads like a code writing request which is off topic for SO. Break your question into its parts and search individually for solutions to those problems. Then, if you are still having issues, please [edit] your question showing your work so we can better help you and the community.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have edited my question with the work I have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you now need to do is

```
$FileNames = @()
foreach ($number in $z) {
    $FileNames += Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object {$_.Name -contains $number}
}
foreach ($FileName in $FileNames) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\MyFolder\$($FileName)" | Out-File -filePath "C:\MyFolder\$($FileName).rpt"
}
```

I'm doing this on my phone so I apologise for any errors, you may also need to tweak the script slightly to remove the .sql.rpt that you'll get as the output format for the Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet

Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: Thanks Random206, That's perfect.